# Is there a way to have "router-outlet" in next.js using the file-based routing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to have "router-outlet" in Next.js using the file-based routing? Meaning that the routes will happen inside a section of a container page (the same way router-outlet works in Angular)?

Comment: I have the exact same question.